# Issue while consuming data from Hono

Tags: eclipse-hono

I have a problem for consuming data using the my IP address when I running  Hono receiver using CLI  as described in [this url](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/getting-started/)

I tried to use this command from hono root by running the jar file using this command

```
sudo java -jar hono-cli-0.9-exec.jar --hono.client.host=myIP--
hono.client.port=15671 --hono.client.tlsEnabled=true --
hono.client.username=consumer@HONO --hono.client.password=verysecret --
spring.profiles.active=receiver --tenant.id=Rad-tenant
```

I have run `Hono` from docker and all service are running and accessible.
Even I can access  the opened ports by docker services for Grafana and prometheus using 3000 and 9090 respectively.
One try that I did is building a dcoker image and running this command from docker in ordered to using exposed docker ports but I got the same error with fewer exceptions see pict [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r78BY.jpg)] which tells the 15671 is closed even it is allocated by docker services.

Comment: First, there should be no reason to run this command as root, i.e. you should not need to put sudo in front of it.
Second, can you post the output that this command generates? It will make finding the reason much easier ...

Comment: Thanks. now it works fine  @kai-hudalla